# Where is the "Publish" operation on Visual Studio 2003?

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio-2003

I've been using the "Publish" operation on Visual Studio 2005 and 2008 (By right-clicking a project under the Solution Explorer and selecting "Publish" on the context menu). Now I was given a ASP.Net web application to modify that was done on Visual Studio 2003. Where can I find the publish operation on Visual Studio 2003?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please refer to the following link.

HOW TO: Deploy an ASP.NET Web Application Using the Copy Project Feature in Visual Studio .NET
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/326356

Comment: @RJ1516. It does support Web Deployment Project since it was the method done when we first deployed the project. However I could use the link you have sent to me. Thanks

Comment: Sorry I just carried away. :) I will just edit my answer. Anyway hope it helps.